# Can't attach USB Device in VirtualBox Error Message

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, rpl

I'm trying to connect to a 32 bit Windows 10 virtual machine on my MacBook. However I am receiving the error messages in the picture below. My VirtualBox version is 7.0.10.

[image]

I have:

- Enabled USB 3.0
- Installed the extension pack for 7.0.10
- Ejected the flash drive from my host machine
- "Insert Guest Additions CD image" does nothing

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to download an older version of Virtual Box.